# Android Default Camera

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, default, android-camera

I am new to Android development.
Can anyone please let me know how to add another button or textEdit on top of Android default camera ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame Layout allows you to put whatever overlays over surface view used for camera. 
Android sample is available in our OCR project ( sampler demo app hat textfield, buttons, 
and images over camera preview )

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to use frame layout. But I cannot find android project on OCR.

Comment: Hi Konstantin, I cannot figure out how to put overlays over default Android camera. I do appreciate if you can help me further. 
Many Thanks

Comment: Short answer - you can not.  You will have to write own camera application. There are demos how to do it - javaocr has one of them

Answer (score 1):

Open the camera in your activity and in your activity layout set `button, textview, edittext` whatever you want...

Comment: Hi Vinnet,
I have tried to put button. But it is not working. I am using default camera. Can you please explain bit more how to load default camera on an activity? Cheers